# Minus a few pixels from jQuery height()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ok, amateur question here but im really bumping my head.

Using the jQuery below, i would like to add margin-top:-100px; to the height value.

Please help! Thanks :)

```
$(function () {
function HomePageSize() {
    $('#home').css({
        width: $(window).width(),
        height: $(window).height()
    });
}
$(window).resize(function () {
    HomePageSize();
});
HomePageSize();
});
```

Comment: Do u want to subtract 100 from height or add the css property `margin-top` to `#home`?

Comment: change here
height: $(window).height()-100 or height: $(window).height()+100
whichever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the css.

```
$('#home').css('margin-top','-100px');
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. Then I realized it was not what I was actually looking for. Daft. How would i remove 100px from the height value instead of a negative margin? Thanks

Comment: Like the guys said below in other answers, you can just subtract 100 from the value.  `height: $(window).height() - 100`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this should do it:

```
$(function () {
function HomePageSize() {
    var winHeight = $(window).height(); // store height in variable
    var myMargin = winHeight - 100; // deduct 100 from height

    $('#home').css({
        width: $(window).width(),
        height: winHeight,
        marginTop: myMargin // assign calculated value to margin-top
    });
}
$(window).resize(function () {
    HomePageSize();
});
HomePageSize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here code:

```
$(function () {

   function HomePageSize() {
       $('#home').css({
           width: $(window).width(),
           height: $(window).height()
       });
   }

   $(window).resize(function () {
       HomePageSize();
   });

  addMargin();

  function addMargin() {
       $('#home').css({'margin-top':'-100px'});
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have margin-top of -100px assigned to some element like #home, then You can try this

```
$(function () {
function HomePageSize() {
$('#home').css({
    width: $(window).width(),
    height:  $(window).height() + parseInt($("#home").css("margin-top"))
});
}
$(window).resize(function () {
 HomePageSize();
});
 HomePageSize();
});
```

Comment: Im not really sure wether this will work. I suggest a `parseInt()\`